# Sequence Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am trying to solve the following sequence question:

> Show that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $A$ if and only if $\{a_n - A\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$.

I start by assuming $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $A$. Now, consider $\{a_n-A\}_{n=1}^\infty$, which is equivalent to $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$-$\{A\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Since we assumed that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $A$ and it follows that the sequence of a constant will converge to the value of the constant, then $A-A=0$. Therefore, $\{a_n-A\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$.

Is that an appropriate proof for the first portion of the iff statement? Or am I completely incorrect? I welcome any suggestion or correction for improvement. 
Thanks.

Comment: Your proof suggestion is somewhat circular. How do you know that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(a_n-A\right)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(a_n\right)-\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(A\right)$?

Comment: It is appropriate if you can use the fact that $\lim_{n} (a_n-A)=\lim_{n} a_n - \lim_{n} A$?

Comment: I was not completely sure if that was true or not. Any suggestions on what I can do the properly solve the question?

Comment: I would suggest using the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=L$ to show that these are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of limit o sequence:

> The limit of a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is $x$ if, for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for every $n > N$, we have $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$.

In your case, you have two sequences: on the one hand, $x_n=a_n$ and $x=A$ and on the other hand, $x_n=a_n-A$ and $x=0$. Note that the expressions on the definiton are the same.